# How to build a module in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-build, android-module

I have a project that has multiple modules:

```
MyProject
    module1  
    module2
```

I would like to generate the APK for module 2.

module 2 has the following instructions in its **build.gradle**:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def file = output.outputFile
        output.outputFile = new File("../module1/src/main/assets", "module2.apk")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to build the APK into module1's assets directory.

Android Studio doesn't seem to have a button for this. If it has, could you please point me on how to find and use it. An added bonus would be to show how to go about it in Terminal. I am on Linux *(Kali Linux)*

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Product flavor like this :

```
 productFlavors {
    module-1{
        applicationId
       "pacakage_name.module-1"
        versionName "1.0-module-1"
    }
    module-2{
        applicationId
        "pacakage_name.module-2"
        versionName "1.0-module-2"
    }
}
```

Debug module 2 then it will generate module 2 apk.For more details 
[Build Varient](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Comment: Do I add this in MyProject build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use product Flavours and can define all of your constants in BuildConfig and initialize them from  Gradle file and make a build by selection of build variants in Android Studio.

[PRODUCT FLAVORS IN ANDROID](http://android.pcsalt.com/product-flavors-android/)

By using product flavours you can add different asset folder in a project  with different resources.

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_ENDPOINT', '"http://api-server.com"'
        }
        uat {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_ENDPOINT', '"http://uat.api-server.com"'
        }
        dev {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_ENDPOINT', '"http://dev.api-server.com"'
        }
    }
}
```